# How to create a template to display data from a class in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a data layer which is returning lists of classes containing data. I want to display this data in my form in WPF. The data is just properties on the class such as Class.ID, Class.Name, Class.Description (for the sake of example)

How can i create a custom control or template an existing control so that it can be given one of these classes and display its data in a data-bound fashion.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a ListBox and set its ItemsSource property to the list containing your data items. Then you define a DataTemplate for your type like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type MyType}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

...and tell the ListBox to use this DataTemplate by setting the [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) property.

It is also sufficient to just define the DataTemplate as above and give it no key. Then it will be used for all items which have the respective type.

BTW: You can find a more detailed example in MSDN on the page for the [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) property.

Comment: Just a followup question. I checked out the MSDN site and a few child links off it, i just need to know one thing about the TargetType or DataType property... If i have a seperate C# project that has a class in it, can i use that class as the type? for instance, project1 has the datatemplate in it, Project2 has a class with the ID, Name and Description. if i use TargetType="{x:Type Project2:DataClass}" will that work? (assuming i have defined a namespace for Project2

Comment: Yes, this should work. Of course, you need to add Project2 as a reference in Project1, so that the type is known. Otherwise, you would not be able to create the appropriate namespace. Just try it out, it should work.  
BTW: I just updated my answer to use `DataType` instead of `TargetType`. Wrote that XAML completely from memory, but I think you already found that little bug. :)